# Pseudo Least Recently Used Binary Tree

Tags: caching, memory, ram

The logic behind Pseudo LRU is to use less bits and to speed up the replacement of the block. The logic is given as "let 1 represent that the left side has been referenced more recently than the right side, and 0 vice-versa"
But I am unable to understand the implementation given in the following diagram:

[image: Pseudo LRU Binary Tree]

Details are given at : http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/ejkim/614/CSCE614-2011c-HW4-tutorial.pptx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm also studying about Pseudo-LRU.
Here is my understand. Hope it's helpful.

- "Hit CL1": there's a referent to CL1, and hit
  LRU state (B0 and B1) are changed to inform CL1 is recently referred.
- "Hit CL0": there's a referent to CL0, and hit
  LRU state (B1) is updated to inform that CL0 is recently used (than CL1)
- "Miss; CL2 replace"
  There's a miss, and LRU is requested for replacement index.
  As current state, CL2 is chose.
  LRU state (B0 and B2) are updated to inform CL2 is recently used.
  (it's also cause next replacement will be CL1)

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an answer which clearly explains the photo, but I wanted to post my way of thinking to implement a fast pseudo-LRU algorithm and it's advantages over classic LRU.

From the memory point of view, if there are **N** objects(pointers, 32/64 bit values) you need **N-1** flag bits and a **HashMap** to store the information of objects( pointer to actual address and position in the array) for querying if an elements exists already in cache. It doesn't use less memory than classic LRU, actually it uses **N-1 auxiliar bits.**

The optimization comes from cpu time. Comparing some flags takes really no time because they are bits. In classic LRU you must have some sort of structure which permits insertion/deletion and you can take the LRU fast(maybe heap). This structure takes **O(log(N))** for a usual operation, but also the comparison between values is expensive. So in the end you end up with O(log(N)^2) complexity per operation, instead of O(log(N)) for Pseudo-LRU.

Even if Pseudo-LRU doesn't always take the LRU object out when there is a cache miss, in practice it seems that it behaves pretty good and it's not a major drawback.